# shared_ptr : "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion function to pointer-to-function type"

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

```
#include "boost\shared_ptr.hpp"

class A{

public:
A(){}
~A(){}

};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptrA;
    ptrA(new A); 

}
```

I would like to know why this code won't compile? I want to know the difference if I just use

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> ptrA(new A);?
```

Comment: This is not really at all specific to `shared_ptr` now is it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> ptrA(new A);
```

Calls conversion constructor which converts `A*` into the `shared_ptr`. This is a default way to construct the ptr.

```
ptrA(new A);
```

Calls `operator()`. This is used for a lot of reasons, one being to make objects emulate functions, i.e functors. But this is not used with `shared_ptr`.

**The constructor exists, `operator()` doesnt.**

Comment: I somehow get it. May I know how to fix it, if I were to call boost::shared_ptr<A> ptrA; and  ptrA(new A);  separately?

Comment: @jko You can do either `ptrA = shared_ptr<A>(new A);` or `ptrA.reset(new A);`

Comment: I was thinking that there might be some time that I would initialize ptrA in other part my code.